# Previous Week H/L Indicator ONLY visible on hourly timeframe and below

Tags: pine-script

I know very little about coding & pine script but I am trying to edit a publically available pine script indicator to only be visible on the hourly timeframe and below. I would greatly appreciate any help on the matter.

The script is made to plot the previous weekly high/low/close on the current week price action. Here is the script:

```
study(title="Week", shorttitle="Week", overlay=true)

highLevel   = input(defval = true, title = "Previous High")
lowLevel    = input(defval = true, title = "Previous Low")
closeLevel  = input(defval = true, title = "Previous Close")

timeFrame   = input(defval = "D", title = "Select Time Frame ( or choose below )
use4hour    = input(defval = false, title = "Use 4 hour?")
useMonth    = input(defval = false, title = "Use Month?")

reso(exp, res) => security(tickerid, res, exp)

tf() => use4hour and not useMonth ? "240" : useMonth and not use4hour ? "M" : timeFrame

highPrev    = change(time(tf())) ? na : reso(high[1], tf())
lowPrev     = change(time(tf())) ? na : reso(low[1], tf())
closePrev   = change(time(tf())) ? na : reso(close[1], tf())

plot(highLevel ? highPrev : na, title = "High", color = silver, linewidth = 2, style = linebr, transp = 50)
plot(lowLevel ? lowPrev : na, title = "Low", color = silver, linewidth = 2, style = linebr, transp = 50)
plot(closeLevel ? closePrev : na, title = "Close", color = silver, linewidth = 2, style = linebr, transp = 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Week", shorttitle="WK", overlay=true)

var color silver50 = color.new(color.silver, 50)
var color green50  = color.new(color.green,  50)
var color red50    = color.new(color.red,    50)

var bool canPlot = (timeframe.isminutes and timeframe.multiplier <= 60) or timeframe.isseconds

[h,l,c] = security(syminfo.ticker, "W", [high,low,close])

if not canPlot
    h := na, l := na, c := na

plot(h, "High",  green50,  2, plot.style_linebr)
plot(l, "Low",   red50,    2, plot.style_linebr)
plot(c, "Close", silver50, 2, plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: ps: if you use `plot.style_stepline` instead of `plot.style_linebr`, the result will look nicer.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn! I think I can just edit that via the indicator settings on the normal interface right? I went with black circles for the formatting because there is no joining line from the values week to week. For some reason only crosses/circles formatting option has a clean break from week to week rather than a joining line which sets off my charting OCD too much! haha. Also I managed to tinker with the code and add a previous month levels on only H4 and previous quarter levels on only D1, so this has made my charting much more efficient, so thanks :)

Comment: Correct. You can adjust plot settings through the indicator settings on the style tab.

Comment: Is it possible to alter the code so it's just straight lines (but without the lines joining up inbetween weeks)? On the old script (which i noticed was version 2 of pinescript) if you add it to a chart you can see it allows this, I just couldn't limit the visibility on any given timeframes for that script. No worries if this isn't possible, I just think that's the best aesthetic for this kind of indicator.